# How to new Cardano.Bip32PrivateKey from cborHex in file .skey generate by cardano-cli

Tags: nami-wallet, cardano-serialization-lib

I'm trying to new `Cardano.Bip32PrivateKey` from string cborHex which in file `skey` generate by cardano-cli

```
import * as Cardano from "@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs";

function genAccountKey(cborHex: string) {
    return Cardano.Bip32PrivateKey.from_bytes(Buffer.from(cborHex, "hex"))
        .derive(harden(1852)) // purpose
        .derive(harden(1815)) // coin type
        .derive(harden(0)); // account #0

}
genAccountKey("58204022747367deee69f601900e15ddc04fc8024753b6a1539ee2a8bed29832f420");
```

but I got this err `(node:87994) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Invalid Secret Key size`

Comment: Is it possible to use .skey(s) and .vkey(s) to construct transactions with the Cardano Serialisation Library? Based on your response it seems as though it is not possible since one cannot backwards derive the necessary privatekeys ...

Comment: Welcome aboard.  Your answer isn't an answer but it would make a good question.  Don't forget to check out the [tour] and read some of the pinned messages in the [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 3):

The CLI key you generate is not the same as Bip32PrivateKey associated with HD Wallet, the Root key you're considering is green box below - while the CLI key is red one. You can derive from parent key to child, but not the other way round.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can derive a private key from skey CBOR using:

````
    // Sign with the backend wallet
    const signingKeyHexCBOR = 'THISISYUURKEYCBOR'
    const signingKey = this.S.PrivateKey.from_normal_bytes(Buffer.from(signingKeyHexCBOR,'hex'));

    const vkeyWitness2 = this.S.make_vkey_witness(txHash, signingKey);
    vkeysWitnesses.add(vkeyWitness);
    ```
````

Comment: do you know how to go the other way? Starting from a Bip32PrivateKey to a CBOR string that I can paste into an skey file that can be used to sign a transaction with cardano-cli?